# How to make autoload field in ActiveForm Yii2

Tags: javascript, jquery, yii2

I need to autocomplete the field grams_net, it is, I want to extract from total_gr disc_gr and the result to be loaded into net_gr

_form:

```
<div class=" col-sm-4">
    <label class="col-sm-12 control-label" for="total_gr">Total gramos:</label>
    <?php echo $form->field($product, 'total_gr', [
    'inputOptions' => ['autofocus' => 'autofocus', 'class' => 'form-control transparent']
    ])->textInput()->input('total_gr', ['placeholder' => "Peso total gr"])->label(false);
    ?>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
    <label class="col-sm-12 control-label nowrap" for="disc_gr">Descont/gr:</label>
    <?php echo $form->field($product, 'disc_gr', [
    'inputOptions' => ['autofocus' => 'autofocus', 'class' => 'form-control transparent']
    ])->textInput()->input('disc_gr', ['placeholder' => "Descont /gr:"])->label(false);
    ?>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
    <label class="col-sm-12 control-label" for="net_gr">Peso neto/gr:</label>
    <?php echo $form->field($product, 'net_gr', [
    'inputOptions' => ['autofocus' => 'autofocus', 'class' => 'form-control transparent']
    ])->textInput()->input('net_gr', ['placeholder' => 'Peso neto/gr:','disabled' => 'true'])
    ->label(false);
    ?>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Can you consider using JQuery too? or you want to use just Javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done using JQuery:

```
use yii\web\View;
```

add unique ids to all three fields:

```
<?php echo $form->field($product, 'total_gr', [
    'inputOptions' => ['autofocus' => 'autofocus', 'class' => 'form-control transparent']
    ])->textInput()->input('total_gr', ['id' => 'total_gr', 'placeholder' => "Peso total gr"])->label(false);
    ?>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
    <label class="col-sm-12 control-label nowrap" for="disc_gr">Descont/gr:</label>
    <?php echo $form->field($product, 'disc_gr', [
    'inputOptions' => ['autofocus' => 'autofocus', 'class' => 'form-control transparent']
    ])->textInput()->input('disc_gr', ['id' => 'disc_gr', 'placeholder' => "Descont /gr:"])->label(false);
    ?>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
    <label class="col-sm-12 control-label" for="net_gr">Peso neto/gr:</label>
    <?php echo $form->field($product, 'net_gr', [
    'inputOptions' => ['autofocus' => 'autofocus', 'class' => 'form-control transparent']
    ])->textInput()->input('net_gr', ['id' => 'net_gr', 'placeholder' => 'Peso neto/gr:','disabled' => 'true'])
    ->label(false);
    ?>
```

add this at the bottom of your view file:

```
$script = <<< JS
    $(document).ready( function () {
        function add(x,y) {
            return (x + y);
        };
        $('input#total_gr').change(function(){
            var y = 0;
            if (!$('input#disc_gr').is(':empty')){
               y = $('input#disc_gr').val();
            }   
            $('input#net_gr').val(add($('input#total_gr').val(), y));
        });
        $('input#disc_gr').change(function(){
            var y = 0;
            if (!$('input#total_gr').is(':empty')){
               y = $('input#total_gr').val();
            } 
            $('input#net_gr').val(add($('input#disc_gr').val(), y));
        });
    });
JS;
$this->registerJs($script, View::POS_READY);
```

Now you can add specific JQuery conditions at the same view file where they needed.

Comment: Hi Serghei, thanks for the reply, I will try to make it work, and I will return the feedback.

Comment: When using this script, the problem is that net_gr has the same value as total_gr and the cause of it may be that the value of disc_gr is not subtracted from total_gr so net_gr is the same. 
The variable disc_gr may have or not a value, it is, sometimes a null value may be subtracted. What may be wrong with it?

Comment: Finally, it works, but I found another problem: the value of net_gr doesn’t arrive at the server.
frontend\modules\admin\models\Product Object
(
    [_attributes:yii\db\BaseActiveRecord:private] => Array
        (
            [category_id] => 1
            [office_id] => 1
            [name] => 1
            [quantity] => 1
            [metal_id] => 1
            [carat_id] => 2
            [total_gr] => 10
            [disc_gr] => 2
            [price] => 250
            [comment] => 
            [created_at] => 2019-07-19 11:20:45
            [id] => 210
        )

Comment: Show what post request are you making.

Comment: Also does my answer help you?

Comment: I tried to solve it, but I could not, I'm learning!

Does Post refer to this?

if ($product->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $product->save())

Comment: i am asking about debug. What $_POST array have you submit. Also, your original question has been answered, so fill free to rate answer. After that open new question that post does not submit all fields, because this need more data to be posted.